# Geosoft Oasis Montaj Local Datum Transform - What is the purpose of this parameter?

Tags: coordinate-system, datum, geosoft

When defining a coordinate system in Oasis Montaj one of the parameters is "Local Datum Transform".  Is this the coordinate transformation definition to convert the defined coordinate system of a data set to WGS84 geographic coordinates?  It is implied in the help docs but is not specifically stated.  Are all OM data sets converted to WGS84 in the "background" based on this parameter?

Answer (score 1):

After posting the question I was able to track down a specific article at Geosoft that answers this.  Yes, the "Local Datum Transform" is used to convert to WGS84.  https://my.geosoft.com/supportcentre?showOverlay=yes&login=ok#kb/kA230000000VFkoCAG

See [Local Datums](https://my.geosoft.com/supportcentre?showOverlay=yes&login=ok#kb/kA230000000VFkoCAG)